# Studying the convergence of $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(in)}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Study the convergence of the following series:$$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(in)}{2^n}$$

$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(in)}{2^n}=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cosh(n)}{2^n}=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^n+e^{-n}}{2^{n+1}}\geqslant\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^n}{2^{n+1}} $

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^n}{2^{n+1}}$

Using L'Hôpital's rule:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^n}{2^{n}}=\infty$ once $e^n$ grows faster then $2^n$.

So the series diverge.

**Questions**:

Is this solution right? Which could be the alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need L'Hopital's rule, just that $e^n/2^n = (e/2)^n$ and $e/2>1$.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use L^Hopital's rule! You can further continue as$$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^n}{2^{n+1}}=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over 2}\cdot\left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^n\ge \sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}{1\over 2}=\infty$$therefore the series diverges.